# SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have now try everything, I use a linux machine with ubuntu 14.04
When i install lodash with npm.

```
$ npm i -g npm
$ npm i --save lodash
```

I come to the first installation and i get:

```
:~/Frontend$ npm i -g npm
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1043:3
```

Please help me, i dont now what to do..

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a more modern version of Node?

Comment: i search to upgrading, but when i try i  get this error all the time.
I cant do anything, do you have an  ide how i can do.

Comment: *when i try i get this error all the time* - what do you try? You should upgrade Node, not NPM. If you have problems upgrading Node, consider asking a relevant question, likely at https://askubuntu.com/ instead of SO.